# It is possible to create a trigger in MySQL when server starts?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Everytime that server starts, I need to set to ON the global variable 'event_scheduler'.
I can't do this in .ini file, because it is manually and I have a lot of clients to do.
So here is the question, it is possible to create a trigger in MySQL to run when server starts to set this variable on?

Comment: Please note the `init-file` option, as suggested by @Zemistr, is not the same as the `.ini` config file. Can you elaborate on why you cannot use the `init-file`? And also, why can you not hard-config the the event scheduler to start? (sorry, I don't fully get the meaning of "because it is manually and I have a lot of clients to do")

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In order to use init-file variable, I have to edit the 'my.ini' and I can't do that manually in five thousands clients. And I can't edit 'my.ini' by my application either, because the application and the server runs in different machines, so I have no way to access the .ini file through network.

Comment: Then I am afraid we have reached a dead-end... Either you are responsible of your client's servers (no pun indended), or your clients have the control. In the first case, you are expected to configure the servers yourself. Obviously this is not the case, otherwise you would hopefully have a centralised infrastructure for such events. I would just advise each of your clients to add one tiny line of configuration to their servers.

Comment: I have the control, but we don't have that centralised infrastructure. So I'll do this: everytime the application starts, I'll set the global variable ON. This way, even when the server restarts, when access the application, the variable returns to ON.

Comment: Wait... Do you have 5k *customers* with one server each (i.e. you need to configure 5k distinct remote *servers*), or do you have one single server and 5k *client applications*, all connecting to this one server?

Comment: 5k customers with one server each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`init-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) variable in your configuration file to run a text file containing SQL statements in it.

Comment: As I said in the question, I can't use the .ini file.

Comment: This looks like the only option :/